# How do I import a column text file with elements with spaces as a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, text-files

I have a .txt file in the following format:

```
A
ABC
ABC DEF
ABCDE

ABCD
```

I want to get a data frame in the following format:

```
    Column Name
1   A
2   ABC
3   ABC DEF
4   ABCDE
```

Comment: try `read.delim("data.txt", header = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `read.delim`

```
read.delim('file.txt', header=F, col.names="Column_Name")
  Column_Name
1           A
2         ABC
3     ABC DEF
4       ABCDE
5        ABCD
```

If you want to keep the empty rows use `blank.lines.skip=F` or `readLines`

```
data.frame(Column_Name = readLines('file.txt'))
  Column_Name
1           A
2         ABC
3     ABC DEF
4       ABCDE
5            
6        ABCD
```